# Cognito with DynamoDB - connecting to us-east-1 instead eu-central-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS DynamoDB with Cognito to authorize access (unauthorized user so far) from Android.
My db is in `eu-central-1` and I use `com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.8`, as:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(context,
    "eu-central-1:XXX", 
    Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1
);
AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
final DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);
```

In logs I see:

> AmazonWebServiceClient: {cognito-identity, eu-central-1} was not found
>   in region metadata, trying to construct an endpoint using the standard
>   pattern for this region: 'cognito-identity.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'

However when I try to fetch data I get:

> User: arn:aws:sts::XXX:assumed-role/XXX/CognitoIdentityCredentials is
>   not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource:
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXX:table/XXX

It seems to connecting to us-east-1 instead of specified EU one. Role has access to proper db resource (EU one), and there is no dynamoDB in US-east. Any ideas where I should specify eu region and I missed it?

Comment: When I execude credentialsProvider.getCachedIdentityId() - I get `eu-central-1:XXX` so it seems that cognito is fine but I do not set DynamoDB location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, so proper way is:

```
ddbClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));
```